# How to set Max Length on ag-grid cells

Tags: max, cell, edit, ag-grid

Is there any way to impose a `maxLength` text allowed in an `ag-grid` cell, similar to the one on a normal input element?

```
  <input maxlength="220"/>
```

No relative documentation was found. Also, no particular situations & more details are needed, in my opinion. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can control the full flow of input data, but you have to create your own [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/) for that.

So - it shouldn't be hard to make a simple input validation.

and to achieve your requirements you have to take care of one function within the component:

```
// Gets called once when editing is finished (eg if enter is pressed).
// If you return true, then the result of the edit will be ignored.
isCancelAfterEnd?(): boolean;

isCancelAfterEnd() {
    return !this.isValid(this.eInput.value);
}

isValid(value) {
    return value.length <= this.maxLength;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fFHnQk2OjGU9BBvadV82?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

agGrid's documentation really isn't clear on this, but it is possible.

[agGrid MaxLength](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/provided-cell-editors/#:%7E:text=The%20agLargeTextCellEditor%20takes%20the%20following,Default%20is%20200)

In your column definitions, just add something like this:

```
this.columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'Surname',
        minWidth: 100,
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: { maxLength: 200 }
    }
```

Comment: Note this doesn't block paste operations from exceeding your limit. For that, you can set a valueSetter that restricts the max length and truncates the value after N characters.